# Get playback devices

Tags: c++, linux, аудио, alsa

Необходимо программно понять, подключено ли какое-то устройство воспроизведения к аудиовыходу. 
Используется linux (МСВС). Пробовал использовать api от alsa, но до реального результата дело не дошло. 
Может кто подскажет примерный путь реализации?

Comment: API от ALSA, ваш Кэп. Только вопрос у вас некорректен. Вы имеете ввиду не аналоговый выход вестимо? Или вам нужен jack sense?

Comment: Имеется ввиду green audio port, куда подключаются наушники, динамики и тд... Вы знаете, каким образом использовать api alsa в данном случае? Пробовал использовать snd_device_name_hint с параметром "pcm". Но там нет информации о подключении. Возможно из snd_ctl_elem_list можно вытянуть данные, но как это сделать корректно?

Comment: Вы очень запутанно пишите. Ищите по ключевым словам **jack sense**.